# Bluemix Node-Red

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, node-red

I am a newbie to Bluemix and Node Red (even stackoverflow). I have tried to create an app in Bluemix using the Node Red and IOT Foundation starter, but neither creates the app. The error message is:

```
BXNUI2028E: Cloud Foundry issued an unexpected exception with the following
message: "Read timed out" See the Troubleshooting topics in the IBM Bluemix
Documentation to check service status, review troubleshooting information,
or for information about getting help.
```

I searched stackoverflow and this problem is mentioned, but is reported as fixed a few days ago. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Some more details, please. BTW: The status for all Bluemix services can be seen here https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status. Sometimes there is scheduled maintenance.

Comment: What region are you using? Does this happen each time you try to create an app?

Comment: Are you still having this issue or is it resolved?

Answer (score 2):

not sure if your case could be similar to this one

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/164719/bxnui2028e-cloud-foundry-issued-an-unprocessed-exc.html

if not I would suggest to open a ticket to Bluemix Support(see the Support tab inside the Bluemix Console) attaching the log as indicated here:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/troubleshoot/getting_customer_support.html#collect_diag

I hope this helps.